# Can't get the meaning of the sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Kindly explain the connection between the first and the last part of this sentence. I can't get the idea in general.

Not only do the apps not communicate anything about me to the restaurants, they clearly know nothing about me because I get email offers from them about underarm laser hair removal. http://techcrunch.com/2014/12/24/the-greasy-underpan-of-restaurant-tech/

Comment: It's just a standard *Not only [statement A], **but also** [statement B]* construction, with the *but also* component implied but not explicitly stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Not only X, Y" simply means that Y, as well as X, is true. In most contexts Y will be a stronger statement than X, perhaps with X as a special case of Y. [Here](https://stancarey.wordpress.com/2009/04/22/not-only-but-also/) is an article with more details about the use of the phrase.

In your example, the speaker starts by saying that "the apps [do] not communicate anything about me to the restaurants" and then continues with the stronger statement that "they clearly know nothing about me", finishing up with an explanation of the latter assertion. It could be rephrased as:

> The apps do not communicate anything about me to the restaurants. Even worse, they clearly know nothing about me. I know this because I get email offers from them about underarm laser hair removal.